# Results from Node/Express using Postgres never send even though they appear in the console

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

My node/Express app is displaying strange behavior.

I have the following code:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express').Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env.local') });
dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const PostgreSqlStore = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SECRET_KEY));
app.use(session({
  store: new PostgreSqlStore({
    conString: `postgres://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`,
  }),
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./auth/passport.js')(passport);

const routes = require('./api/routes')(router, passport);

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})

module.exports = app;

// /api/routes.js
const api = require('./api');

module.exports = function(router, passport) {
  router.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    api.getUsers(req, res, next);
  })

  return router;
}

// /api/api.js
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const initOptions = {
  promiseLib: Promise,
}

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);

const db = pgp({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
});

const getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  db.task(t => {
    return t.any('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uuid ASC')
      .then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  })
}

module.exports = {
  db,
  getUsers,
}
```

If I run the server and cURL `localhost:5000/users` the app just sits there and doesn't return any data. However, if I Ctrl + C to stop the server connection, it gives me the following:

`curl: (18) transfer closed with 1 bytes remaining to read`
The weird thing is that this is followed by the data that's missing! I.e. it's not getting sent until the server is shut down.

Postman call never gives a response.

Console.logging `result` outputs the expected/missing data in the console.

The data's there, but `res.send` and `res.json` are doing nothing. I'm sure it has to do with Promises, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've also tried to use Pools and Clients for the database queries, instead of `pg-promise`, but to the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I needed to use `Pool` correctly and tie it into the session.

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express').Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env.local') });
dotenv.config();
const pool = require('./api/api').pool;
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const PostgreSqlStore = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.options('*', cors());
app.use('*', bodyParser.json());
app.use('*', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SECRET_KEY));
app.use(session({
  store: new PostgreSqlStore({
    pool,
  }),
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./auth/passport.js')(passport);

const routes = require('./api/routes')(router, passport);

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})

module.exports = app;

// api/routes.js

const api = require('./api');

module.exports = function(router, passport) {
  router.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    api.getUsers(req, res, next);
  })

  return router;
}

// api/api.js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
});

const getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    return client.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uuid ASC', (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(error);
      } else if (result.rowCount > 0) {
        res.send(result.rows);
      }
      else {
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
    })
  })
}

module.exports = {
  pool,
  getUsers,
}
```